# Site to request example code

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which site can I use to request example code for subjects that I'm new to?

I've tried Stack Overflow and Programmers in the past and my questions always get closed and voted down so I'm not sure if there is an appropriate site for this or not?

**edit:**

---

Some advantages of learning a new topic using examples:

1. Clearly defined starting point
2. Start with what works, not what doesn't
3. Working code provides motivation to explore more and learn more
4. Provides only what you need, when you need it
5. Differentiating between good articles and bad ones becomes easier (execute the code, see the result and either stick around or move on)

Comment: Google, bing, Yahoo!, Baidu, Excite, Altavista, Metacrawler, ...

Comment: Language documentations often have code examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such site within the SE network.

Questions that ask for example code would indeed get closed. On stackoverflow you'll find on the [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as as the reason:

4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Although it might seem weird or even maybe rude at first here are a few things I consider important for this rule to exist:

- It encourages the users of SE to learn and grow their collective knowledge instead of being simple copy-cats
- It forces OP's to focus on solvable problems instead of having ready-cooked meals.
- It gives a bigger chance the question and its answers are usable for a larger audience, not only beginners.

That said it shouldn't be too hard to find tutorials in any technology, most vendors offer that kind of documentation and a lot of open-source projects have some great technical writers in their community. Conferences (with their material published, on youtube for example) are another great way to pick-up new stuff. And last but not least the tag wiki's on every site within the SE network provide more often than not valuable resources.

If that all fails or doesn't exist you could still ask a succesful question if your question is just a small step on the learning curve. If you show what you are trying to achieve, a small step, a couple of lines of code, a to the point error you could get a great answer with lot of code or guidance that points you in the right direction.

That said, there are some site proposals on Area51 that might come close to what you ask, or at least your take away could be, not today, maybe next year...

- [code recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations)
- [code understanding](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding)

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a site that this question would be appropriate on, no.

When I'm in need of examples the first place I look at is the documentation of whatever language/project I'm using. Not all documentation is fantastic but where it's not a number of people have already posted on their blogs or answered Stack Overflow questions about the topic. So, my second place is normally a comprehensive Google search.

Depending on how complex the problem is a search can take *weeks* (no I'm not joking). It takes weeks because once I've found a likely method method of doing something I have to test whether it's correct. Maybe after 30 minutes you think you've found your answer but in a days time you find a bug so you have to work out how to fix the bug; or, start from the beginning again.

Once you've done all this and understand why it's *still* not working you have a Stack Overflow question. If you get it to work you have a Stack Overflow question *and* answer (you searched properly first right?).

Comment: Just a minor additional point: when working with an open-source project/library, I find that looking at the library code itself also often provides insight, independent of whether the documentation or examples are lacking.

Comment: I feel that while it may be *possible*, it's not always the fastest or most efficient way to start learning simply by pulling your hair out for weeks.

Comment: Obviously if you're just learning a language then a week is a massive exaggeration for every question you have. My point is that before you ask a question you should know exactly what you don't understand and why. Just asking for samples doesn't help you fulfil either of those criteria, especially as there's likely to be tens of thousands (if you're just starting) of samples on the internet already, many of them in Stack Exchange.

Comment: I guess that's just about creating a question format that meets answerable acceptance criteria. Sometimes samples are either not accurate or do not exist and therefore it's quicker and more efficient to request them.

Comment: If they're not accurate then you've already worked out why @ThreaT. To reiterate, simply asking for samples is not a good question and it is likely to be closed. Though it might be quicker for you, it's not quicker for everyone else, so please make an effort first. See also: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/458741)

Comment: Assume you've done your research and you've found nothing of use. Assume you've read every piece of documentation you can find and got nothing from it. Perhaps someone else has experience and would be able to provide the example you're looking for. If so, why not? Also, bounties could be used for questions that require a lot of effort, just like difficult problems on StackOverflow. I also find that there's no place to ask simple questions which an example would implicitly answer. For example: "How do online payments work?" would be voted down and closed in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I've already answered your first point, if you're learning a language then the examples likely already exist on Stack Exchange - just look. To your second, you're assuming that Stack Exchange has to so everything, it doesn't. Your question would be downvoted and closed because it's off-topic. The descriptions of what is on-topic is available in the [help] (and you're forced to read them before posting); not sure why we should be catering to people who ignore the community who are already here.

Answer (score 2):

I predict that any such Stack Exchange site would be doomed. Questions would likely be asking others to do the author's work for them. Acceptance criteria would either be unclear or excessively demanding. The reward for answering wouldn't be commensurate with the effort involved in asking questions.